# Замена document.ready

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте. Стоит на сайте функция

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".show-commnets").click(function(){
      //функция
    });
```

Без `$(document).ready(function(){ });` функция не срабатывает, но и каждая страница подгружается в DIV блок через `load()` (JS в отдельном файле и подключен выше подргрузки) и из-за этого функция не хочет работать, если я просто перейду на страницу, не через подрузку, то все работает.

**Вопрос: как мне можно исправить данную проблему?**

Answer (score 0):

Если данный js код вызывается при загрузке сайта, то он не будет работать для новых элеменов на странице (в том числе подгруженных аяксом)

Для отслеживания новых элементов используется .on (version added: 1.7) или .live(version deprecated: 1.7, removed: 1.9) смотрите используемую версию jquery

```
$(".show-commnets").on('click', function(){
      //дуйствие
    });
```

Comment: Всё равно не работает. Версия JS самая последняя.

Comment: @Aue, не работает, потому что ставить надо на контейнер, куда эти элементы добавляются, а не на сами элементы.

Answer (score 0):

Решил данную проблему по простому, сделал событие `onClick='name();'`

```
<a onClick='showcommnets();'>Text</a>

  function showcommnets() {
  }
```

Comment: Смешивание html и js — плохое решение.